# Change specific part of a line in a file with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a line in a autoexec.py file that I want another script to be able to modify:

```
kodi.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(/path/to/file)")
```

I was thinking of using sed to override the value within PlayMedia() depending on certain conditions.

Can sed be used to only touch and overwrite the parts between the PlayMedia() brackets and nothing else? Or is further processing/regex needed?

Comment: So you want to replace what is within `PlayMedia()`? Sure, `sed` can suffice. Give more details about what exactly what you want to do: is this line occurring many times in the file? does it have to be a path? do you want to replace with the content given by a variable or just hardcode something?

Comment: It is only one reference, it is a path to a playlist file. I just need to modify the value within PlayMedia()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sed. The below code will replace the chars present inside the brackets following  `PlayMedia` string with `foo`.

```
sed 's/\b\(PlayMedia\)([^)]*)/\1(foo)/g' file
```

If the string you want to replace is a path, you must use a different sed delimiter because filepath may contain forward slashes.

```
sed 's~\b\(PlayMedia\)([^)]*)~\1(foo)~g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'kodi.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(/path/to/file)")' | sed 's/\b\(PlayMedia\)([^)]*)/\1(foo)/g'
kodi.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(foo)")
```

Comment: Just a note this throws sed: bad option in substitution expression when foo is a file path like /path/to/something

Comment: @James in that case, use a different sed delimiter like `sed 's~\b\(PlayMedia\)([^)]*)~\1(foo)~g'`

Comment: Yes I was just about to post a changed delimiter version. I was looking at an example that used something like ^A. Thanks for posting an update!